# How to disable popup prompt for password in xrdp session? IOW, how to convince Ubuntu that my XRDP session is the console?

Tags: login, password, xrdp

I have a dual boot system, Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04. When I boot into Linux, or if I use Hyper-V with enhanced session off, I don't get prompted for my password, except at login, or after the screen locks.

However, most times that I use the Linux system is via Hyper-V enhanced session, which appears to connect via XRDP. In this mode, I get prompted for my password *a lot.* Sometimes half a dozen times for "refreshing the system repositories" and then again because "the login keyring did not get unlocked..." when starting up some apps.

From my research, it appears that this is because Ubuntu sees me (correctly!) as not logged in at the console. Is there a good way to tell Ubuntu to treat XRDP sessions as if they were the console session? Or other good way to globally eliminate these popups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior and it's triggered by the polkit software solution...

To fix your issue, you have to create exception rules that will be applied when connecting remotely via xRDP software...

To keep it short, create a file in **/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/** and name it **45-allow-colord.pkla**

in this file, copy the following code

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

To fix your specific issue about system repositories refresh, you will need to create also another file that you can name 46-allow-update-repo.pkla (in the same directory as specified above i.e. /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/)

```
[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Comment: Thank you, Griffon. I already had the first file in place with the same content, which must have come up in a previous search on this topic. It seems like adding the second file has obviated the need for entering the password when the system tries to refresh repos. But, I do also get prompted when powering down the system, or when starting Chrome, or .....         Hence my wish for a setting that allowed the OS (or polkit more specifically, I guess) to consider this session to legitimately serve as the console. Current approach feels very piecemeal.

Comment: But if that's all there is, my followup would be -- is there a way for an ordinary user to figure this out? It sure would be handy if, for instance, the popup had a little triangle that when you clicked it expanded the window to show what Action was being questioned. That feels like the one piece of info I would need to create such a file. (I'm assuming the names are semi-arbitrary, and that polkit simply enumerates all of them and applies them in order)

Comment: Hello Tastewar  sorry for the late answer... so to get rid of all prompt, you could try to set the value for Action to Action=*.  This should tell the system to allow any operations...Never tried that but we think it should work... hope this help

Comment: Thanks again, Griffon! That seems to have eliminated the need for the password when powering down the VM, but I am still prompted for the password to the Default keyring.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to tasteware's question about "is there a way for an ordinary user to figure this out? It sure would be handy if, for instance, the popup had a little triangle that when you clicked it expanded the window to show what Action was being questioned."

You can see a log of what actions caused any recent password prompts with:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
```

In Ubuntu 22.04, I also had to add these actions to 46-allow-update-repo.pkla (separated with a semicolon):

org.debian.apt.update-cache

org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages